# Dell 34" curved monitor cracked and displays lines

Tags: display, hardware-failure

I've been using this screen for a few years now and it got hit and cracked and started showing lines.

It's a Dell U3415Wb 34" curved monitor.

Is there a DIY way of fixing it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. That's busted.
The LCD panel itself is damaged. That's a no-fix.

It would be cheaper to buy a new display than attempt a repair.

Comment: In other words "Its dead,Jim"